# What does this red part mean?

Tags: 18.04, disk-usage

I have an external hard disk which format as the ext4, I know the green part is I have used space, and the gray part is mean not used, but there has another red part, what does this mean?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

[image: Pic]

THX

Comment: What application produces this pie chart?

Comment: I am guessing here, but it could be the default 5% reserved space that ext3/4 has. You can remove it with this command: *sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdXX* where XX would be the device letter and partition number. In your case you may even be able to run this: *sudo tune2fs -m 0 /media/hero*

Comment: @OrganicMarble The disk folder's properties.

Comment: @GTrawo THX, I just want to know what this means, for the sake of data security I am not going to execute these commands. ^^

Comment: @Hatsune Good choice. It's not necessary to run those commands. But if you want to read up more on setting the reserved space take a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250418/tune2fs-how-much-space-to-reserve-on-large-ext4-filesystem